Total system hangs following a Ubuntu Update
For just over a week, maybe 2 weeks, following an update to Ubuntu 22.04, I began experiencing "freeze-ups" and total hangs, necessitating a hard reboot.  I, on occasion, have been told to use fsck to clean up. That works 1/2 the time so there likely is another issue. I have never had an issue like this since I began using Ubuntu.
I performed BIOS-based memory tests and SSD tests. No faults found.
After reading the forum I also assessed the wayland vs X.org problem especially related to Firefox. I implemented the wayland deactivation.
I get hangs before I launch ANY applications.  I get total hangs which prevent terminal kill actions. The issue resides in something that seizes control of the task operations. Browser independent hangs.
I have, at times, managed to get the system monitor running in a effort to see if a process can be identified as taking over the priority. Nothing helpful there.
I have sent multiple reports to Ubuntu upon reboot error message requests.
Ubuntu changed something critical during the last update. I have no idea what that may have been.
Reading this forum tells me that it isn't just my computer.
Has Ubuntu issued a patch or fix?

Check for overheating. Maybe your computer is full of dust.

Is it the same if you boot from your previous kernel? For grub menu during boot either shift (BIOS) or esc (EFI) then select previous kenel. 24.04 (6.8) updated on 23/08/24 for me, &; 22.04 (6.5) 18/08/24  & for 20.04 (5.4) 10/08/24. (That is when I updated them in the usual way.)

"Reading this forum tells me that it isn't just my computer." yet it's none of mine, so it's not universal, and might not be due to an update. Read your apt log to see what was changed during the "last update"

Sorry. Last kernel update for 22.04 was from 6.5... to 6.8.0.40 not as I originally stated. (24.04 current kernel is 6.8.0.41 (or it was on 23/08/24).
